# UITableViewCell with UITextView blocks UI

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitableview

I have a UITextView inside a cell, and when scrolling the UI freezes for a short but noticeable time waiting for the cell to be created.

Any similar experience with textviews? Why would that take time to create such a cell? Could it be created on a background thread to avoid the freeze?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self setupTextView];
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return self;
}

- (void)setupTextView
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.4f;
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;

    textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    [self.contentView addSubview:textView];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:textView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:-18.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:textView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:-18.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:textView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:0.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:textView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:0.0]];

    _textView = textView;
}
```

Comment: can you paste your cellforRowAtIndexPath Code ? so that we can help better

Comment: Just posted the code for the cell

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something terribly wrong with cell reuse. Usually no cells are created while scrolling

Comment: And why don't you use prototype cells? They will definitely make your life easier a lot

Comment: I am using the classic pattern : registering the cell in view did load, and then dequeing it, so nothing wrong about it. What do you mean by prototype cell?